# Will SSL affect the performance of a socket.io app?

Tags: security, ssl, socket.io, dns, ssl-certificate

I want to buy SSL and add to my domain, but my concern is about performance and speed. my concern is: Will SSL affect the speed of my chat app ? as it is implemented with `socket.io`.

currently I am connecting with `http : // mydomain.com` but after adding SSL I would use `https : // mydomain.com`, so will `https` affect the speed of my `socket.io` app ?

My conditions is:

1. Performance and speed is a must
2. Security also is a must

Comment: It'll barely be noticeable, especially for a chat app. Use TLS, this shouldn't even be a question any more.

Comment: Hello @Marc, thank you very much, Could you please kindly explain a little more and will you suggest me to use SSL?

Comment: Providing privacy, data integrity, and server authentication should not be a question any more. Yes, use SSL, or TLS as it's called these days.

Answer (score 2):

If security is a must then you should use SSL. It prevents people from being able to listen in on your conversations so I wouldn't trust a site if it didn't have a signed SSL certificate.

The impact on performance is so negligible that I wouldn't worry about it. There are so many other things you can do to improve the speed of your app that if your app is ever noticeably slow, it probably won't be due to SSL.

Comment: Thank you so you are suggesting to use ssl?

Comment: Absolutely. If that answers your question could you mark it as "answered". Thanks mate!

Comment: Thank you very much, still I am a little confusing about it. If I even use it in mobile application not browser can still it have its benefits ?

Comment: Becuase I am using only for mobile app, I dont have website, I am using the domain only for accessing socket.io connections

Comment: Yes, any client application, even a mobile app, should use SSL.

Comment: Is encryption and decryption did in each user's request ? or it just does for the first request

Comment: @Muhammad All HTTPS requests are encrypted, all HTTP requests are not.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, if security is important to you, then you should indeed encrypt your network traffic with SSL/TLS.

There is technical overhead to establishing a new SSL/TLS session, and encrypting/decrypting traffic back and forth.  But on modern CPUs/networking hardware, that overhead is usually negligible, you may not even notice any delays.  Years ago, that was not the case, but technology has evolved alot since the early days of the Internet, and now use of SSL/TLS is very commonplace, even recommended/required in many modern systems.

Comment: if the data end-to-end encrypted still, will it be useful? example I encrypt the message before sending and decrypt while receiving each message with AES algorithm

Comment: @Muhammad if the data is encrypted outside of the wire, there is no need to encrypt the wire itself as well. But, there is more to SSL/TLS than just encryption, it also provides for identity validation, too (making sure you are actually communicating with the correct peer you are expecting)